# I need help understanding the replacement of TWO in the below code

Tags: c, macros

I ran it through Code::Blocks and it shows me the final answer 1. How is TWO then replaced in the " i = i-2*TWO" statement and why is like that?

The code is part of a homework exercise I'm trying to solve/understand:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
    #define  ONE    1
    #define  TWO    ONE + ONE
    int main(void) { 
        int i = 2;
        i = i - 2 * TWO;
        printf("%d\n", i);
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: Think like a preprocessor!

Comment: It will be replaced as `i = i - 2*1 + 1`, which yields result 1.

Comment: This is a simple one, but for more complex macros, some (or maybe all) compilers have an option to save the pre-processed code file. For example: [How do I see a C/C++ source file after preprocessing in Visual Studio?](//stackoverflow.com/q/277258)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make the substitution yourself.

```
i = i - 2 * TWO;
```

is

```
i = i - 2 * ONE + ONE;
```

So you have

```
i = 2 - 2 * 1 + 1;
```

So i will have the value 1.

If you want to get the result equal to -2 then rewrite the macro like

```
#define  TWO    ( ONE + ONE )
```

Comment: So it's not like in mathematics when you do the same replacement: i = i-2*TWO =  i = i-2*(ONE+ONE)  = 2 -2*(1+1)= 2-4 = -2 ?

Comment: @painkiller It is like in mathematics because you are not using parentheses.

Comment: Ok I get it, thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can see what the compiler sees as final expression by running `gcc -E <filename.c>`.  That should help in understanding why the result is 1.